# Вопрос по поводу отображения отдельной страницы товара

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmyadmin

**Не пинайте.** У меня есть index.html где выводятся товары магазина из БД с помощью php. Как правильно реализовать, то, чтобы по нажатию на товар открывалась его страница. Не писать же отдельно страницу для каждого товара. Если можно, то как можно подробнее опишите пожалуйста. Делаем товар кликабельным, а ссылку тогда какую? Понятно что через БД как-то, но пока не понятно для меня это. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: прежде чем пытаться что-то программировать возьмите прочитайте вот любую книжку по пхп. прямо вообще любую. самую маленькую, самую дешевую, вообще. не там где "для профессионалов" а для "осваиваем пхп за 3 часа".

Comment: Есть страница. При обращении к ней передаешь параметром id товара, например. По этому id товара шебуршишь базу данных. Извлекаешь нужные данные, формируешь страницу, показываешь пользователю. Всё